# CSS grid layout appears to float left?

Tags: css, layout, css-grid

My grid was working perfectly until I made some changes, 5 days have passed without resolution with rigorous work, I have simplified it, for an easier read. I have also made sure to add clear fix's to the floats of elements inside the near top grid items.

I have used `grid-template-areas` and `grid-template-columns` to adjust the size of the columns and show where each grid item should go. However, when I render the web page all the items are aligned to the far left column, except for my `navbar` and hero image which have been set to 100% width, they are fine. The desired grid layout is detailed at the bottom of the CSS file standalone and with media queries.

have a good day, thanks for reading (I am a novice)

***HTML CODE***

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Home</title>
        <link href="normalize.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>

<body>

    <div class="wrapper">

        <header class="navbar">
            <a id="top"></a>

            <img class="logo" src="randimage.png" alt="title" style=height:20px;>
            <nav class="topnav">
                <ul>                    
                    <li><a href="#">Learning journal</a></li>                   
                    <li><a href="/tutorial.html">Tutorial</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/contact.html">Contact me</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
            </header>



        <div class="hero-image">
            <div class="hero-text">
                <h1>Learning Journal</h1>
                <p>This is a log of my journey in learning how to design a web site.</p>
            </div> 
        </div>

        <nav class="week-nav">
                <h2 class="contenthead">Weekly Posts</h2>
                <ol>
                    <li><a href='#week1'>Introduction to Web Design</a></li>
                    <li><a href='#week2'>Learning how to make web pages</a></li>
                    <li><a href='#week3'>Learning about lists, quotes and tables</a></li>
                    <li><a href='#week4'>CSS basics</a></li>
                    <li><a href='#week5'>CSS box model & styling text</a></li>
                    <li><a href='#week6'>Responsive web design</a></li>
                    <li><a href='#week7'>RWD2</a></li>
                    <li><a href='#week8'>RWD3</a></li>
                    <li><a href='#week9'>HTML5 & CSS forms</a></li>
                    <li><a href='#week10'></a></li>
                    <li><a href='#week11'></a></li>
                    <li><a href='#ref'>References</a></li>
                </ol>
</nav>

        <div class="table">
            <table>
                <caption><strong>Personal timetable</strong></caption>
                <tr>
                    <th>Day/Time</th>
                    <th>Monday</th>
                    <th>Tuesday</th>
                    <th>Wednesday</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>9-10am</td>
                    <td>e</td>
                    <td>e</td>
                    <td>--</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>10-11am</td>
                    <td>e</td>
                    <td>e</td>
                    <td>e</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>11-12pm</td>
                    <td>e</td>
                    <td>e</td>
                    <td>e</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>12-1pm</td>
                    <td>e</td>
                    <td>--</td>
                    <td>--</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>1-2pm</td>
                    <td>--</td>
                    <td>e</td>
                    <td>--</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>2-3pm</td>
                    <td>e</td>
                    <td>--</td>
                    <td>--</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>3-4pm</td>
                    <td>e</td>
                    <td>--</td>
                    <td>--</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>4-5pm</td>
                    <td>e</td>
                    <td>--</td>
                    <td>--</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
</div>

        <div class="main">

                <main>

                    <h2>Learning Journal</h2>

                    <article>
                        <header class="post">
                            <a id="week8"></a>
                            <h3>Week 8:</h3>
                            <p>Published on<time datetime="2019-12-20"><strong> December 20, 2019</strong></time></p>
                        </header>

                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In molestie aliquet felis sed finibus. Proin eleifend arcu at est euismod eleifend. Ut vulputate lorem eu nisi condimentum suscipit. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Mauris tempor non purus dignissim placerat. Ut commodo, lacus in ultricies mattis, diam augue sollicitudin nisl, sagittis gravida elit tellus eu ex. Nam pellentesque egestas nisi, ac semper nulla sagittis id. Donec ligula elit, aliquet eget placerat in, accumsan sit amet mi. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Integer lacinia odio ut ornare aliquam. Donec et erat vel sem volutpat lobortis eu vel massa. Nullam sit amet dui ac nibh dignissim mollis eget nec nibh.</p>



                    </article>

                                <article>
                        <header class="post">
                            <a id="week7"></a>
                            <h3>Week 7:</h3>
                            <p>Published on<time datetime="2019-12-18"><strong> December 18, 2019</strong></time></p>
                        </header>

                        <h3>Flexible media</h3>

                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In molestie aliquet felis sed finibus. Proin eleifend arcu at est euismod eleifend. Ut vulputate lorem eu nisi condimentum suscipit. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Mauris tempor non purus dignissim placerat. Ut commodo, lacus in ultricies mattis, diam augue sollicitudin nisl, sagittis gravida elit tellus eu ex. Nam pellentesque egestas nisi, ac semper nulla sagittis id. Donec ligula elit, aliquet eget placerat in, accumsan sit amet mi. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Integer lacinia odio ut ornare aliquam. Donec et erat vel sem volutpat lobortis eu vel massa. Nullam sit amet dui ac nibh dignissim mollis eget nec nibh.</p>

                    </article>

                    <article>

                        <header class="post">
                            <a id="week6"></a>
                            <h3>Week 6:</h3>
                            <p>Published on<time datetime="2019-12-16"><strong> December 16, 2019</strong></time></p>
                        </header>

                        <h3>Week 6 outline:</h3>
                        <ul>
                            <li>Reflection & changes</li>
                            <li>Wireframes</li>
                            <li>Responsive grid layout workflow</li>
                            <li>RWD for mobile</li>
                            <li>Media queries</li>
                            <li>Making images flexible</li>
                            <li>Testing responsiveness of web page</li>
                        </ul>

                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In molestie aliquet felis sed finibus. Proin eleifend arcu at est euismod eleifend. Ut vulputate lorem eu nisi condimentum suscipit. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Mauris tempor non purus dignissim placerat. Ut commodo, lacus in ultricies mattis, diam augue sollicitudin nisl, sagittis gravida elit tellus eu ex. Nam pellentesque egestas nisi, ac semper nulla sagittis id. Donec ligula elit, aliquet eget placerat in, accumsan sit amet mi. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Integer lacinia odio ut ornare aliquam. Donec et erat vel sem volutpat lobortis eu vel massa. Nullam sit amet dui ac nibh dignissim mollis eget nec nibh.</p>

                    </article>

                    <article>
                        <header class="post">
                            <a id="week5"></a>
                            <h3>Week 5:</h3>
                            <p>Published on<time datetime="2019-12-10"><strong> December 10, 2019</strong></time></p>
                        </header>

                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In molestie aliquet felis sed finibus. Proin eleifend arcu at est euismod eleifend. Ut vulputate lorem eu nisi condimentum suscipit. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Mauris tempor non purus dignissim placerat. Ut commodo, lacus in ultricies mattis, diam augue sollicitudin nisl, sagittis gravida elit tellus eu ex. Nam pellentesque egestas nisi, ac semper nulla sagittis id. Donec ligula elit, aliquet eget placerat in, accumsan sit amet mi. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Integer lacinia odio ut ornare aliquam. Donec et erat vel sem volutpat lobortis eu vel massa. Nullam sit amet dui ac nibh dignissim mollis eget nec nibh.</p>


                    </article>

                    <p><a href="#top">Go to top</a></p>

                </main>
</div>

        <div class="aside">  
            <aside>

                <a id="ref"></a>

                <h2 class="contenthead">References</h2>

                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Archive/Mozilla/Migrate_apps_from_Internet_Explorer_to_Mozilla">Examples of Web Standards</a></li>
                        <li><a href="https://www.linkedin.com/learning/html5-structure-syntax-and-semantics/what-are-web-semantics?u=67552674">HTML5: Structure, Syntax and Semantics</a></li>
                        <li><a href="https://www.w3schools.com/html/">HTML definitions & concept clarity</a></li>
                        <li><a href="https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element">HTML elements reference</a></li>
                        <li><a href="https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/html-tutorial/html-lists.php">HTML Lists</a></li>
                        <li><a href="https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/cite">Quoting framework</a></li>
                        <li><a href="https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Selectors/Type_Class_and_ID_Selectors">Type, class and ID selectors</a></li>
                    </ul>

            </aside>
        </div>  

        <div class="footer">
            <footer>
                <a href="mailto:(myemail@service.com)">Email [myname]</a><br>
                <small>&copy; 2020, fname sname.</small>
            </footer>
        </div>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

***CSS CODE***

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald&display=swap');
/*importing google font*/

* {box-sizing: border-box;}

#wrapper {
    display: grid;
    max-width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: #fff;
    font-family: "helvetica neue", sans-serif;
    font-size: 1em;
}
body {
    /*background-image: url("/ci435/images/BG_IMAGE.png");*/
    /*background-repeat: repeat;*/
    /*un-comment these when you have created round boxes for each element containing raw text*/
}

.navbar {
    max-width: 100%;
    padding: 1em 1em;
    background: #000;
    height: 3em;
    width: 100%;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}

a { text-decoration: none; color: #2c3ad1; }
a:hover { text-decoration: underline; }
a:visited { color: #5c13bd; }
a:active { color: #e8d05a; }

.topnav {
    height: 3em;
    font-weight: bold;
    list-style: none;
    float: right;
}
main {
    clear: left;
}
.topnav li {
    display: inline-block;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    line-height: 1.2em;
    font-size: 0.7em;
    text-indent: 3em;
}
.topnav ul {
    position: relative;
    bottom: 2.5em;
    right: 1.6em;
}

.topnav a:link { color: lightgrey;}
.topnav a:hover { 
    color: #fff;
    border-bottom: 1000px #fff
}
.topnav a:visited { color: #fff; }

.logo {
    height: 20px;
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
}

.navbar:after {
    content: "";
    visibility: hidden;
    display: block;
    clear: both;
}
table {
    background-color: #FFF;
    border: solid 4px #4682B4;
    border-spacing: 0;
    text-align: center;
}
tbody tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #B0C4DE;
}
th {
    background-color: #4682B4;
    padding: 3px;
}
caption {
    font-size: 1.3em;
    padding-bottom: 0.5em;
    /*space between caption and the table underneath*/
}
.hero-image {
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 175, 255, 0.4), rgba(117, 19, 93, 0.73)), url("/ci435/images/bannerImages/lj.jpg");
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 70vh;
    /*justify-content: center;*/
}
.hero-text {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    color: white;
}

/*GRID LAYOUT*/
.navbar {
    grid-area: navbar;
}
.hero-image {
    grid-area: hero;
}
.week-nav {
    grid-area: week-nav;
}
.table {
    grid-area: table;
}
main {
    grid-area: main;
}
aside {
    grid-area: aside;
}
footer {
    grid-area: footer;
}

/*LAYOUT STYLES*/
#wrapper {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-areas:
        "navbar"
        "hero"
        "week-nav"
        "table"
        "main"
        "aside"
        "footer";
}

@media (min-width: 750px) {
    #wrapper {
    grid-template-columns: 3fr 7fr;
    grid-template-areas: 
        "navbar  navbar"
        "hero  hero"
        "week-nav  table"
        "week-nav  main"
        "aside  main"
        "footer  footer";
    }
}

@media (min-width: 1000px) {
    #wrapper {
        grid-template-columns: 1fr 3fr 1fr;
        grid-template-rows: auto;
        grid-template-areas: 
                 "navbar  navbar  navbar"
                 "hero  hero  hero"
                 "week-nav  table  aside"
                 "week-nav  main  aside"
                 "footer  footer  footer";
        }
}


@media (max-width: 500px) {
    table {
        display:none;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your issues are coming from your css selectors.

First, your grid isn't getting applied because in your css, you use an id selector (#wrapper), but in your html you give it the class, not id, "wrapper". **Changing either the html to an id or the css to a class will fix this** - if you think it is a wrapper pattern you will reuse then set it as a class, otherwise I'd recommend changing the html to set id="wrapper".

Next, the selectors you use to assign the grid-areas for main, aside, and footer are all the tag selectors. The issue here is that each of your main, aside, and footer elements are wrapped in divs inside of wrapper, so hierarchically it's actually #wrapper -> div container -> main/aside/footer. The grid-area attributes of each main/aside/footer are therefore unused as they look in their immediate parent, the div container, for the grid-template-areas when it is really in the #wrapper. **To fix this, you can either move the grid-area attributes in your css from the tag selector to the div container selector, or if the div containers are otherwise unused, remove them entirely.**

Here is the modified css to work with grid:

```
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald&display=swap");
/*importing google font*/

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#wrapper {
  display: grid;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: #fff;
  font-family: "helvetica neue", sans-serif;
  font-size: 1em;
}
body {
  /*background-image: url("/ci435/images/BG_IMAGE.png");*/
  /*background-repeat: repeat;*/
  /*un-comment these when you have created round boxes for each element containing raw text*/
}

.navbar {
  grid-area: navbar;
  max-width: 100%;
  padding: 1em 1em;
  background: #000;
  height: 3em;
  width: 100%;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #2c3ad1;
}
a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
a:visited {
  color: #5c13bd;
}
a:active {
  color: #e8d05a;
}

.topnav {
  height: 3em;
  font-weight: bold;
  list-style: none;
  float: right;
}
main {
  clear: left;
}
.topnav li {
  display: inline-block;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  line-height: 1.2em;
  font-size: 0.7em;
  text-indent: 3em;
}
.topnav ul {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 2.5em;
  right: 1.6em;
}

.topnav a:link {
  color: lightgrey;
}
.topnav a:hover {
  color: #fff;
  border-bottom: 1000px #fff;
}
.topnav a:visited {
  color: #fff;
}

.logo {
  height: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
}

.navbar:after {
  content: "";
  visibility: hidden;
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
table {
  background-color: #fff;
  border: solid 4px #4682b4;
  border-spacing: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
tbody tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #b0c4de;
}
th {
  background-color: #4682b4;
  padding: 3px;
}
caption {
  font-size: 1.3em;
  padding-bottom: 0.5em;
  /*space between caption and the table underneath*/
}
.hero-image {
  background-image: linear-gradient(
      to bottom,
      rgba(0, 175, 255, 0.4),
      rgba(117, 19, 93, 0.73)
    ),
    url("/ci435/images/bannerImages/lj.jpg");
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 70vh;
  /*justify-content: center;*/
}
.hero-text {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  color: white;
}

/*GRID LAYOUT*/
.navbar {
  grid-area: navbar;
}
.hero-image {
  grid-area: hero;
}
.week-nav {
  grid-area: week-nav;
}
.table {
  grid-area: table;
}
.main {
  grid-area: main;
}
.aside {
  grid-area: aside;
}
.footer {
  grid-area: footer;
}

/*LAYOUT STYLES*/
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas:
    "navbar"
    "hero"
    "week-nav"
    "table"
    "main"
    "aside"
    "footer";
}

@media (min-width: 750px) {
  .wrapper {
    grid-template-columns: 3fr 7fr;
    grid-template-areas:
      "navbar  navbar"
      "hero  hero"
      "week-nav  table"
      "week-nav  main"
      "aside  main"
      "footer  footer";
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1000px) {
  .wrapper {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 3fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: auto;
    grid-template-areas:
      "navbar  navbar  navbar"
      "hero  hero  hero"
      "week-nav  table  aside"
      "week-nav  main  aside"
      "footer  footer  footer";
  }
}

@media (max-width: 500px) {
  table {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

Hope this helps!